# How to run HtmlUnit.jar in terminal/command line?

Tags: html, unit-testing, htmlunit

I am searching for a way for testing my webpage using the command line.

My intentions are

- check an anchor tag is present on the page
- check the anchor tag href is pointing to the correct(pre-defined) web link
- Check the anchor tag text is the pre-defined one
- I should be able to check other tags also like img, script, etc.

After searching, I came across [htmlUnit.jar](https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/htmlunit). But I am not getting any proper link on how to run this in the command line.

- Will I be able to pass the test cases to the jar file? If so, please guide me
- What is the syntax to run this htmlUnit.jar file in the terminal? I am unable to find any useful documentation

Please help if I can achieve my goal by this file

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit is a library, you have to write your own program using HtmlUnit for your use case.

Another option is to use Wetator ([www.wetator.org](http://www.wetator.org)).
Wetator is

- based on HtmlUnit
- runs from the command line
- can perform the different asserts you like to do
- generates a nice report (and also a return code if at least one assert fails)

(Ok, i'm the person behind HtmlUnit and Wetator so maybe i miss some other option)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tool. Let me go through this and try in command line

Comment: Please open an issue at github if you have any problems and i will try to help.

Comment: I tried Wetator. But it purely depends on the text that is displayed in the DOM. So I am creating my own program using Java and HTMLUnit